# Evaluate the integral: $\int{\frac{1}{x\sqrt{\ln{x}}}}.dx$

Tags: integration, substitution, integration-by-parts

I am looking to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int{\frac{1}{x\sqrt{\ln{x}}}.dx}$$

but I cannot figure out how to solve it by substitution or by parts. Using the integration by parts, I separated the equation as follows:

$$\int{\frac{1}{x}.\frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln{x}}}.dx}$$

but I keep getting even more complicated equations. Any suggestions on solving this?

Comment: Hint: Use the substitution  $$\ln(x)=t$$

Comment: No `\large`, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int { \frac { 1 }{ x\sqrt { \ln { x }  }  } dx } =\int { \frac { d\left( \ln { x }  \right)  }{ \sqrt { \ln { x }  }  } = } 2\sqrt { \ln { x }  } +C$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{\ln x}}$$
Take $x=e^u$. Then
$$=\int \frac{e^{-u}}{\sqrt u}\cdot e^u du$$
$$=\int \frac{du}{\sqrt u}$$
$$=2\sqrt{u}+C$$
$$=2\sqrt{\ln(x)}+C$$
And there you go!